# Is there a workaround for a Hall effect encoder out of alignment with its sensors on a small motor?

Tags: dc-motor, hall-effect, rotary-encoder

I'm working with two budget [SmartArduino 9V 25mm motors](http://www.smartarduino.com/25mm-9v-dc-reduced-gear-motor-for-robot_p94537.html) on a radio control tank project.

Motor-A has a problem in that the encoder wheel is situated laterally above the Hall sensors. Motor-A does not produce pulses on the hall sensors without intervention. [image: MotorA encoder]

Motor-B's encoder has a very small overlap with the hall sensors. Motor-B does produce pulses on the hall sensors as the motor is manually rotated. [image: MotorB encoder]

There is lengthwise play in the shaft on which Motor-A's encoder wheel is fixed. If I press down on the encoder wheel while manually rotating the motor, then the Motor-A does produce pulses on the hall sensors. [image: Intervention]

Q1: Is there an optimal position for the placement of the encoder wheel in relation to the hall sensors? I had assumed that they would have been more overlapping with the face of the encoder wheel.

Q2: Are you able to suggest a workaround or repair to correct the situation?

Comment: Looks like the PCB is attached to the motor by being soldered to the 2 tabs. I'd apply a soldering iron to reach one at a time to lift the PCB up slightly away from the motor.

Comment: What brhans says OR melt solder on hall cells and pull out slightly OR add iron or steel shims on top of hall cells. Or...

Comment: Push the magnet wheel down, so that its surface will overlap with the hall sensor surface as much as possible.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Yeah I had a look at that it seems to be quite firmly fixed and i wasn't sure how much force it can withstand. It seems to have hot glue fixing it, do you know if the heat gun will likely damage the magnetic wheel?

Comment: I have no idea how it looks like. Maybe the PM ring is fitted/glued on top of the metal wheel which is screwed laterally on the shaft. You would need to find the separate mounting instructions for that type of encoder. The assembly was wrong, the guy had no idea how it should be done correctly.

Comment: RussellMcMahon, brhans, thanks good suggestions. I got out the magnifying glass and identified the sensor face markings as [3144 916X] (https://components101.com/asset/sites/default/files/component_datasheet/A3144%20Hall%20effect%20Sensor.pdf) so replacing the sensors and leaving longer leads is another option.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, you're right there! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source](https://www.rhydolabz.com/robotics-robotic-parts-c-155_164/magnetic-encoder-pair-kit-for-20d-mm-metal-gearmotors-p-2323.html)

> Once the board is soldered to the motor, the magnetic encoder disc can
> be pushed onto the motor shaft. One easy way to accomplish this is to
> press the motor onto the disc while it is sitting on a flat surface,
> pushing until the shaft makes contact with that surface.Pushing the
> disc a little closer to the PCB can ensure strong signal and good
> performance.

You could use a flat surface with a hole to push further or to put it on bench vise.